# Firefox won't run

Tags: windows, firefox, troubleshooting

Upgraded to FF3.5.x: initially, only problem was several extensions (Tab Mix Plus, Personal Menu) wouldn't work. Rebooted/restarted, but not only didn't help, FF itself wouldn't run (at all). Uninstalled/reinstalled both FF 3.0.x and 3.5.x, rebooted PC -- no joy. Noticed that with Task Manager open, trying to boot FF was followed by a brief (2-3 seconds) appearance of process "firefox.exe" but promptly disappeared.  Running FF Safe Mode didn't work; rebooted Windows in Safe Mode, but FF still wouldn't launch. Was able to start Profile Manager, but button for New Profile didn't function.

Comment: Did you try installing 3.5 directly (not an upgrade from 3.0)? Did you try FF Portable (http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)? I have no idea what the problem is; I did the same things with the same extension problems, but it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try a fresh install in a *different* directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation seems to be corrupted.
Since you have already tried an uninstall and reinstall once,
Suggest you try a cleanup of the install with something like [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

Then, do a fresh install.

Checking that a [portable edition](http://portableapps.com/news/2009-08-04_-_firefox_portable_3.5.2) works fine is also a good idea.